# Kivy Image Child Class Produces Two Images

Tags: python, image, canvas, graphics, kivy

I think this is probably a simple miss understanding about something deeper in kivy, but I have an RoundedImage class that is producing two images, where one is the original without rounded corners and one with the rounded corners off screen a bit. Whats going on?

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCQac.jpg

I think it may be something to do with subclassing Image?

```
class RoundedImage(Image,StyleUnit):

    _styleist = RadialGradientStyleist    
    _radius = [20]
    _source = ''
    _style = None
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):

        super(RoundedImage,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self._source = source
        #self.initalizeStyle()

        with self.canvas:
            StencilPush()
            self.m_rect = RoundedRectangle( size = self.norm_image_size , \
                                            pos=self.center, \
                                            radius=self._radius)
            StencilUse()
            self.rect = Rectangle(  size = self.norm_image_size , \
                                    pos = self.center, \
                                    texture = self.texture)
            StencilUnUse()
            StencilPop()
            #Color(1,1,1)
            #self.line = Line(   rounded_rectangle=self.pos+self.size+self._radius,
            #        width=10)


        self.bind(pos = self.update_rect,
                  size = self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self,*args):
        self.m_rect.pos = self.center
        self.m_rect.size = self.norm_image_size
        self.rect.pos = self.center
        self.rect.size = self.norm_image_size
```

The application code is simple:

```
class ProfilesApp(App):

    def build(self):
       profile = RoundedImage( source = source,#self.imageLocation,\
                                    allow_stretch=True)
       return profile

profileApp = ProfilesApp()
profileApp.run()
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this ended up being an issue of not removing a mask in the stencil instructions.

I ended up adding this to the .kv definition for the RoundedRectangle

```
'''
<-RoundedImage>:
canvas:
Color:
rgb: self.color
StencilPush
RoundedRectangle:
size: self.norm_image_size
pos: self.center[0] - self.norm_image_size[0]/2.0,self.center[1] - self.norm_image_size[1]/2.0
radius: self._radius
StencilUse
Rectangle:
texture: self.texture
size: self.norm_image_size
pos: self.center[0] - self.norm_image_size[0]/2.0,self.center[1] - self.norm_image_size[1]/2.0
StencilUnUse
RoundedRectangle:
size: self.norm_image_size
pos: self.center[0] - self.norm_image_size[0]/2.0,self.center[1] - self.norm_image_size[1]/2.0
radius: self._radius
StencilPop

'''
```

Answer (score 1):

No imports, no other required classes and although I've seen that rounded rectangle somewhere, I don't have a clue what does that custom class do, so no runnable code. Let's work with that anyway.

Yes, it's because of that subclassing - the picture is already placed in the canvas and you use the texture of it which is there in `Rectangle(texture=<here>)`. Instead of that remove subclassing of the image *and* use `source` keyword argument for the `Rectangle` like this:

`Rectangle(source=<path to image>)`

Then again although you use `source` in your class that inherits from `Image`, you need to change that and fetch the `source` from kwargs:

`self.source = kwargs.get('source')`

then instead of `Rectangle(texture=self.texture)` do `Rectangle(source=self.source)`